# Sympy package solve() didn't give all the solution for root(x,3)

Tags: python, sympy

I was using sympy package and solve() to get the roots of equations, where

```
 solve(x-root(4*x,3),x)
```

only give result as 0 and 2.
but the (all) solutions could be obtained by manually simplified as

```
 solve(x**3-4*x,x)
```

as 0,2,-2.

My question was that why by using the root(x,3) not giving all the solutions?
How exactly was it working/(to determine that it had all the solutions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, n-th root is a multivalued function. The [documentation of root function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#root)  says:

> `root(x, n, k)`  Returns the k-th n-th root of x, defaulting to the principal root (k=0).

You can get other roots by passing in the parameter k, as follows:

```
[solve(x-root(4*x, 3, k), x) for k in range(3)]
```

returns `[[0, 2], [-2, 0], [0]]`.

Or, to make a set of all solutions,

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable([solve(x-root(4*x, 3, k),x) for k in range(3)]))
```

results in `{-2, 0, 2}`.